# 3D plot is noisy

Tags: plotting, graphics, eigenvalues

I have the following 3x3 matrix, dependent on the variables $k_{x}$,$k_{y}$ :

```
H[kx_,ky_]:={{0, -2 t12 Cos[{kx, ky} . d12], -2 t13 Cos[{kx, ky} . 
 d13]}, {-2 t12 Cos[{kx, ky} . d12], 0, -2 t23 Cos[{kx, ky} . d23]}, {-2 t13 Cos[{kx,ky} .d13], -2 t23 Cos[{kx, ky} . d23], 0}}
```

Where $d_{12}$,$d_{13}$,$d_{23}$ are constant vectors:

```
d12 = {1, 0};
d13 = {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
d23 = {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
```

and $t_{12}$, $t_{13}$,$t_{23}$ are real parameters.
Let's say that $t_{12}=t_{13}=t_{23}=1$.
What I want to do is to Find the eigenvalues of the matrix H, which will depend on $(k_{x},k_{y})$, and plot them as 3D functions in the $k_{x}$-$k_{y}$ plane.
My problem is that If I do (considering for example the first eigenvalue):

```
Eigen[kx_, ky_] := FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[H[kx, ky]]][[1]]
Plot3D[Eigen[kx, ky], {kx, -3 - 3}, {ky, -3, 3}]
```

I get a very noisy and discontinuous plot:

[image]

However, If I print the output of Eigen[kx_ky_] by:

```
Eigen[kx,ky]
```

which is:

```
Root[16. Cos[1. kx] Cos[0.5 kx - 0.866025 ky] Cos[
 0.5 kx + 0.866025 ky] + (-6. - 2. Cos[2. kx] - 
  4. Cos[1. kx] Cos[1.73205 ky]) #1 + #1^3 &, 1]
```

And I directly plot it as:

```
 Plot3D[Root[16. Cos[1. kx] Cos[0.5 kx - 0.866025 ky] Cos[
 0.5 kx + 0.866025 ky] + (-6. - 2. Cos[2. kx] - 
  4. Cos[1. kx] Cos[1.73205 ky]) #1 + #1^3 &, 1], {kx, -3 - 3}, {ky, -3, 3}]
```

The plot I get is smooth, as it should be:

[image]

So My question is: first of all, what does the notation "#" mean in the expression of the eigenvalue? And secondly how can I obtain the second smooth plot without copying and pasting the output for the eigenvalue every time?

Comment: Where is code about `print the output of Eigen[kx_ky_]`

Comment: See Edit. Anyways I get the output by running the code: Eigen[kx,ky]

Answer (score 3):

- We can do this by using `=` instead of `:=`.
- We also insert the values by `/. {t12 -> 1, t13 -> 1, t23 -> 1}`.

```
Clear[H, Eigen];
H[kx_, ky_] = {{0, -2 t12 Cos[{kx, ky} . d12], -2 t13 Cos[{kx, ky} . 
       d13]}, {-2 t12 Cos[{kx, ky} . d12], 
    0, -2 t23 Cos[{kx, ky} . d23]}, {-2 t13 Cos[{kx, ky} . 
       d13], -2 t23 Cos[{kx, ky} . d23], 0}};
d12 = {1, 0};
d13 = {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
d23 = {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
Eigen[kx_, ky_] = FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[H[kx, ky]]][[1]]
Plot3D[Eigen[kx, ky] /. {t12 -> 1, t13 -> 1, t23 -> 1}, {kx, -3, 
  3}, {ky, -3, 3}]
```

[image]